# Force laravel to send emial with a coustom configuration not used in .env file

Tags: laravel, email, frameworks

I have a Laravel app, the code crypted by [phpBolt](https://github.com/arshidkv12/phpBolt) (vondor folder not crypted) and I want to force to set an email configuration.

I try to changed from Mail class but it doesn't work

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). You can then start writing an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your config on runtime using config()->set():

```
config()->set('mail.mailers.[your_mailer].[host/port/username/...]', 'value');
```